# Is there a way where we can call methods from .so file directly in robot framework?

Tags: automated-testing

I have a c++ code which upon build gives me .so file. I want to use the methods from that .so file into my robot framework. Any suggestions please.

Comment: what is your use case ? usually calls will be made from Robot to external binaries (aka C++ code) not the other way around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own test library that would support calling functions of your *so* within Robot framework. Here is [the official guidelines for creating test libraries](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries). As they recommend in the guidelines, in order to integrate the code of shared libraries to your tests you should use [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) python library in your robot framework test library code.